# How do I access this data

Tags: javascript

I'm currently going through codesmith's CSX and I came across this problem. The idea is to create a function that takes two callbacks as arguments and if any input passed either one of those functions return the function that passed. I can't figure out how to access the input data. Sorry if I'm not clear enough.

```
function eitherCallback(cb1, cb2) {
  // ADD CODE HERE
  
}

//please try to solve without editing the code underneath
function filterArray(array, callback) {
  const newArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
    if (callback(array[i], i, array)) newArray.push(array[i]);
  }
  return newArray;
}

const arrOfNums = [10, 35, 105, 9];
const integerSquareRoot = n => Math.sqrt(n) % 1 === 0;
const over100 = n => n > 100;
const intSqRtOrOver100 = eitherCallback(integerSquareRoot, over100);
console.log(filterArray(arrOfNums, intSqRtOrOver100)); // should log: [105, 9]
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to make `eitherCallback` return a function which takes an array item and tests whether it passes `cb1`'s test or `cb2`'s test:

```js
function eitherCallback(cb1, cb2) {
  return item => cb1(item) || cb2(item);
}

//please try to solve without editing the code underneath
function filterArray(array, callback) {
  const newArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
    if (callback(array[i], i, array)) newArray.push(array[i]);
  }
  return newArray;
}

const arrOfNums = [10, 35, 105, 9];
const integerSquareRoot = n => Math.sqrt(n) % 1 === 0;
const over100 = n => n > 100;
const intSqRtOrOver100 = eitherCallback(integerSquareRoot, over100);
console.log(filterArray(arrOfNums, intSqRtOrOver100)); // should log: [105, 9]
```

Another way to think of it - if you have two callbacks and you want to filter an array by whether an item passes either callback, you would do:

```
arr.filter(
  item => cb1(item) || cb2(item)
);
```

This is the same sort of thing, except that the function is funneled through some slightly confusing levels of additional abstraction.

Comment: I'm a little confused how javascript knew what the item was did it just pick that information up from array[i]? I'm trying to break it down but I just don't understand why this item is equal to array[i]. I also don't get why the or statement works in this case.

Comment: On every iteration, it does `callback(array[i])`. This `callback`, here, is the `eitherCallback` function; it gets invoked with the current array item, and if the return value is truthy, the item gets pushed to the array.